# Viewport for site too wide for iPad not working

Tags: wordpress, ipad, viewport

I'm working on a site www.turistadimestiere.com and its width is 1052px plus 20px padding either side. I have the viewport in the header set to  but the wide site is not scaling down to to fit the screen in landscape or portrait. It's not letting me tap to zoom either.

I have worked on other sites that have the same set up and do scale correctly in both orientations.

Can anyone take a look and help please? I've tried loads of variations of viewport but nothing seems to make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. There is some sort of conflict with the WP Responsive Menu plugin. Deactivated it and now all ok.